# Find item with `Contains` condition using Express and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to search for items in my collection where the userName contains `adm`.

I expect to get 2 results, because I have 2 records in my database where the userNames are `admin0` and `admin2`, but it does not return anything.

I'm using this query :

```
Person
  .find({
    userName: { $in: 'adm'}
  })
```

What is the problem? How can I search and find persons where the userName contains `adm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use regular expression or `$regex` when finding the Persons.

Here is the snippet:

```js
Person.find({username: {$regex: '(.*)adm(.*)'}})
```